# user information and the course name with time spend in a course

Tags: moodle

Can anybody help me out with the code to get the user's firstname, lastname, the course name and the time spend by the user on that course in moodle 2.6? Using configurable reports doesnot give me the exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following sql to find the course participants.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM mdl_user u JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT eu1_u.id FROM mdl_user eu1_u JOIN mdl_user_enrolments eu1_ue ON eu1_ue.userid = eu1_u.id JOIN mdl_enrol eu1_e ON (eu1_e.id = eu1_ue.enrolid AND eu1_e.courseid = 4) WHERE eu1_u.deleted = 0 AND eu1_u.id <> 1 ) e ON e.id = u.id LEFT JOIN mdl_user_lastaccess ul ON (ul.userid = u.id AND ul.courseid = 4) LEFT JOIN mdl_context ctx ON (ctx.instanceid = u.id AND ctx.contextlevel = 30) ORDER BY u.lastaccess DESC;
```

There are two ways to find the time spend in a course:

1. If course completion is enabled and the user has completed the course, then the time spend in the course will be the difference between the timestarted  and timecompleted fields in mdl_course_completions table.
2. You can also calculate the time spent in a course from moodle logs.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you gnuwings for the reply. I used the mdl_logs table to calculate the time spent.

Comment: I wonder if there is any table in moodle to keep trace of the time spend by the user in daily basis?

Comment: As said earlier, if course completion is enabled, then you can fetch this from mdl_course_completions table